# Database Design method to solve one column references to 2 tables in specific problem

Tags: database, database-design

I need to design a database model for a delivery management system, and I'm facing an issue with the following tables: transactionpoints, goodspoints, and employees. The purpose of these tables is evident from their names. The transactionpoints table has a one-to-many relationship with the goodspoints table. I want the workAddressID column in the employees table to reference either the transactionpointID in the transactionpoints table or the goodspointID in the goodspoints table.

If I stick to these three existing tables, it seems impractical with SQL. However, as per my research in some other articles, some have proposed a solution: creating a general-purpose table called routingpoints to act as an intermediary to connect the goodspoints and transactionpoints tables. Both goodsPointID and transactionPointID would reference routingpointID. Then, the workAddressID from the employees table would reference routingpointID. This method sounds reasonable and promising. However, the person suggesting this solution has emphasized that it's not a good practice because it complicates maintenance and makes coding more complex.

My team has proposed an alternative solution, which involves removing the goodsPointID and transactionPointID tables and replacing them with a single routingpoints table that contains all the attributes of the two original tables. Additionally, a goodsPointID column is added, and it has a value when a point is a transactionPoint; otherwise, it is null. This solution is acceptable up to this point. However, the issue is that the two original tables have differing sets of attributes, resulting in many records in the new table having some null values.
If I had to choose between these two solutions, I would opt for the latter. Is there a way to address this issue? I believe that, in this specific problem, there might be a more suitable and optimized solution.

In addition, the employees table also has an enum role column. Is there any way to constrain a transactionpoint to only have 1 employee according to roleA and 2 employees according to roleB?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can you represent inheritance in a database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3579079/how-can-you-represent-inheritance-in-a-database)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution 1:** You can simply create two columns in the employee table transactionpointID and goodspointID, instead of single column workAddressID, and add a constraint that only one of them should be null.

**Solution 2:** You can use a single column as workAddressID and another column as workAddressType(enum) to store type of address(e.g. 1 for transactionpointID and 2 for goodspointID), and finally create a trigger to check the foreign key presence manually, that is, if the workAddressID is present in either of the tables on the basis of workAddressType.